# php assoc array

Tags: php

I have two assoc array i want to creat one array out of that
E.g

```
a(a=>1
  b=>3
  f=>5 
 )
b(a=>4
  e=>7
  f=>9 
 )
```

output must be

```
c(
   a=>1
   b=>3
   f=>5 
   a=>4
   e=>7
   f=>9 
)
```

i am new in php

Comment: Think about it: when you access `$c['a']` what would PHP give you back? You could use nested assoc arrays. `$c[0]['key'] == 'a' and $c[3]['key'] == 'a'`

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_merge()](http://php.net/array_merge). Your resulting array CAN NOT have more than one entry for the same key, so the second a => something will overwrite the first.

Comment: No, an associative array can only contain one value for each key. Of course, you can make your values into arrays. To do that, look into `array_walk()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`+` operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) to return the union of two arrays.

The new array is constructed from the left argument first, so `$a + $b` takes the elements of $a and then merges the elements of `$b` with them *without* overwriting duplicated keys. If the keys are numeric, then the second array is just appended.

This ey difference of the `+` operator and the function, [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) is that array merge overwrites duplicated keys if the latter arguments contain that key. The documentation puts it better:

> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended.

Comment: I do not understand your question. I think the linked examples sould explain everything.

Comment: In `$a + $b`, PHP does not overwrite keys/values in `$a` with keys/values from `$b`. With `array_merge($a, $b)` it does.

Answer (score 0):

If the keys are different, then use `array_merge()`

```
<?php
    $a1=array("a"=>"Horse","b"=>"Cat");
    $a2=array("c"=>"Cow");
    print_r(array_merge($a1,$a2));
?>
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array ( [a] => Horse [b] => Cat [c] => Cow )
```

If the keys are the same, then use `array_merge_recursive()`

```
<?php
    $ar1 = array("color" => array("favorite" => "red"), 5);
    $ar2 = array(10, "color" => array("favorite" => "green", "blue"));
    $result = array_merge_recursive($ar1, $ar2);
    print_r($result);
?>
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [color] => Array
        (
            [favorite] => Array
                (
                    [0] => red
                    [1] => green
                )

            [0] => blue
        )

    [0] => 5
    [1] => 10
)
```